# Error question when using recursive function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm implementing a bulletin board comment function, but I'm blocked from looking up comments.

I made a recursive function to make the big comments appear under the comments, but I keep getting errors, but I don't know where the problem is.

```
window.onload = () => {
      findAllComment();
    }

// 전체 댓글 조회
    function findAllComment() {

      const postId = [[ ${post.id} ]];
      const accountId = [[ ${account.id} ]]

      $.ajax({
        url: `/api/posts/${postId}/comments`,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {

          console.log(response);

          // 1. 조회된 데이터가 없는 경우
          if (!response.result.data.length) {
            return false;
          }

          // 2. 렌더링 할 HTML을 저장할 변수
          let commentHtml = '';

          // 3. 댓글 HTML 추가
          response.result.data.forEach(row => {
            commentHtml += `
                              <div class="card py-0 mt-3">
                                  <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                      <span class="comment-writer"><span class="card-text">${row.account.nickname}</span></span>
                                      <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:if="${row.account.id == accountId}">
                                          <a class="comment-delete" onclick="deleteComment(${row.id});"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">삭제</span></a>
                                          <a class="comment-edit" onclick="findEditComment(${row.id});"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">수정</span></a>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="comment-reply" onclick="findReplyComment(${row.id})"><i class="fa fa-comment fa"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">답글</span></a>
                                      <span class="date" id="commentDate">${dayjs(row.createdDateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <span class="comment-content"><span class="card-text">${row.content}</span></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <!--/* 답글 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_reply_view${row.id}"></div>

                              <!--/* 댓글 수정 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_edit_view${row.id}"></div>

                              <!--/* 댓글 답글 작성 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_createReply_view${row.id}"></div>
                            `;

            if (row.children.length) {
              row.children.forEach(childRow => {
                findChildComment(row.id, childRow);
              })
            }
          })

          // 4. class가 "cm_list"인 요소를 찾아 HTML을 렌더링
          document.querySelector('.cm_list').innerHTML = commentHtml;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
    }

    // 답글 조회
    function findChildComment(parentId, child) {

      var idForInnerHtml = '#cm_reply_view' + parentId;
      const accountId = [[ ${account.id} ]];

      let commentHtml = `
                              <div class="card py-0 mt-3">
                                  <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                      <span class="comment-writer"><span class="card-text">${child.account.nickname}</span></span>
                                      <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:if="${child.account.id == accountId}">
                                          <a class="comment-delete" onclick="deleteComment(${child.id});"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">삭제</span></a>
                                          <a class="comment-edit" onclick="findEditComment(${child.id});"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">수정</span></a>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="comment-reply" onclick="findReplyComment(${child.id})"><i class="fa fa-comment fa"></i><span class="card-text ml-1">답글</span></a>
                                      <span class="date" id="commentDate">${dayjs(child.createdDateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <span class="comment-content"><span class="card-text">${child.content}</span></span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <!--/* 답글 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_reply_view${child.id}"></div>

                              <!--/* 댓글 수정 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_edit_view${child.id}"></div>

                              <!--/* 댓글 답글 작성 뷰 */-->
                              <div id="cm_createReply_view${child.id}"></div>
                            `;

      if (child.children.length) {
        child.children.forEach(childRow => {
          findChildComment(child.id, childRow);
        })
      }

      document.querySelector(idForInnerHtml).innerHTML = commentHtml;
    }
```

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" error occurs at "document.querySelector(idForInnerHtml).innerHTML = commentHtml;" last line of 'findChildComment ' method.

I checked through logs that <id="cm_reply_view${row.id}"> and <var idForInnerHtml = '#cm_reply_view' + parentId;> has same value, but I don't know which part is the problem. If anyone knows, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: are you sure that element exist by the time you do `document.querySelector(idForInnerHtml).innerHTML = commentHtml;` ? If that element is created via ajax, then is very likely that ajax is not done by the time you try to get that element

Comment: ah... Is it correct to say that the line `<div id="cm_reply_view${row.id}"></div>` does not exist because the ajax processing never completed? @Chris G

Comment: yes, ajax is an async request, Gotta take that into consideration

Comment: I don't think that the Ajax asynchrony is the issue here though, because the whole process starts when the request comes back with the result (in the `success` handler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the HTML *after* having performed the recursion. Yet the recursive calls need the HTML with the parent `div` to already be present in the document. So you need to reverse the logic a bit.

Here are some changes to the code that should make it work:

- In the `success` callback, in step 3, first finish the `forEach` loop before making recursive calls:

  ```
  response.result.data.forEach(row => {
      commentHtml += /* Your HTML Comes here */ ;
  }); // Finish the top HTML first, then load the collected HTML into the document
  document.querySelector('.cm_list').innerHTML = commentHtml;
  // And only now perform the recursion, which needs that HTML 
  // to already be present in the document.
  response.result.data.forEach(row => {
    if (row.children.length) {
      row.children.forEach(childRow => {
        findChildComment(row.id, childRow);
      })
    }
  })
  ```
- A similar change is needed in `findChildComment`:

  ```
  let commentHtml = /* Your HTML comes here */;
  // Again: first assign the HTML that you need for the recursive calls
  document.querySelector(idForInnerHtml).innerHTML = commentHtml;
  // ... and then make the recursive calls:
  if (child.children.length) {
    child.children.forEach(childRow => {
      findChildComment(child.id, childRow);
    })
  }
  ```

Comment: Aha, since html is not allocated until the recursion ends, it ends the iteration and starts iterating again to recurse.
Thank you I'll fix it as you said and move on.

Comment: If it works out for you, let me know (It is always nice to get feedback).

Comment: I succeeded in retrieving the reply of comment by editing as you just answered!
I spent several hours on this problem and wrote a question, and thanks to you, it was clearly solved. Thank you so much! @trincot

Comment: Nice to hear! Thanks for the feedback!